# How to create a onefile executable from a python script?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, executable

I have a decently complicated .py script, which uses several packages, incl matplotlib, numpy, and one custom, that is compiled from a fortran code. I want to make a windows executable out of this, that is distributeable in a way, that users don't need to have python installed on their computers for it to work.

When I make my .exe with `pyinstaller --onefile myprogram.py` the resulting .exe doesn't run on its own (if I doubleclick on it, the GUI it contains doesn't open), however, if I have anaconda installed, from anaconda prompt I can run it with `.\path\to\program\myprogram.exe` and it works all nicely (without creating an environment with matplotlib etc)

My question is: how can I make it so that the one file includes all the dependencies and I can just doubleclick on it and go?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open a command window and run the .exe from there, that should show you the errors and why it's not working. Either post them here or, if they're errors with importing, then my next question would be if you're using a virtual environment as that'll probably be the cause and something you need to handle in your `.spec` file

Comment: I literally get no error messages, it just sits there for a while and exits with no exit code or whatever..... how can this be handled in the .spec file?

Comment: I think you'd need to show your code to help more with that. As for the imports, if you are using a virtual environment then set up a variable within the `.spec` file to the `site-packages` directory `packages_dir = '/your-venv/Lib/site-packages'` and then add `packages_dir` to the `pathex` section of your `.spec` e.g. `pathex=['.', packages_dir],`

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately this did not solve it, I added the site-packages directory to the spec file as you described and rerun pyinstaller with it, but I have the same thing, I click on the .exe, a console opens, stays there for a minute then disappears, no error message

Comment: you'll need to show some of the code for me to be able to assist further. Considering it's supposed to have a GUI and that's not showing it would be helpful to see the __main__ block and how you've set up the GUI to launch

Comment: with some print debugging I have found that the .exe crashes when it reaches `fitted = opt.curve_fit(function_tofit, x_data, y_data, p0=p_0)`. I do have `import scipy.optimize as opt` in the beginning. if I remove every instance of scipy.optimize stuff being used, the program runs well, but sadly, they are essential (edit: and the program runs perfectly from jupyter notebook and within the conda env)

Comment: @throughalfnoir Are you able to do some exception handling and provide the error you're getting when it crashes? If you're not seeing an error it sounds like you might be covering them up with some blind try/excepts. My guess at this point though is that there's something specific about scipy that's having trouble importing the module or part of it so best to look up Pyinstaller and Scipy, both are popular so I'm sure someone's come across this issue before